# Backing up API Keys for recovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am designing and implementing a backup plan to restore my client API keys. How to go about this ?

To fasten the recovery process, I am trying to create a backup plan for taking the backup of Client API keys, probably in s3 or local. I am scratching my head from past 2 days on how to achieve this ? May be some python script or something which will take the values from apigateway and dump into some new s3 bucket. But not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all apigateway API keys list using `apigateway get-api-keys`. Here is the full AWS CLI command.

```
aws apigateway get-api-keys --include-values
```

Remember `--include-values` is must to use otherwise actual API Key will not be included in the result.
It will display the result in the below format.

```
"items": [
        {
            "id": "j90yk1111",
            "value": "AAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCC",
            "name": "MyKey1",
            "description": "My Key1",
            "enabled": true,
            "createdDate": 1528350587,
            "lastUpdatedDate": 1528352704,
            "stageKeys": []
        },
        {
            "id": "rqi9xxxxx",
            "value": "Kw6Oqo91nv5g5K7rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr",
            "name": "MyKey2",
            "description": "My Key 2",
            "enabled": true,
            "createdDate": 1528406927,
            "lastUpdatedDate": 1528406927,
            "stageKeys": []
        },
        {
            "id": "lse3o7xxxx",
            "value": "VGUfTNfM7v9uysBDrU1Pxxxxxx",
            "name": "MyKey3",
            "description": "My Key 3",
            "enabled": true,
            "createdDate": 1528406609,
            "lastUpdatedDate": 1528406609,
            "stageKeys": []
        }
}
]
```

To get API Key detail of a single API Key, use below AWS CLI command.

```
aws apigateway get-api-key --include-value --api-key lse3o7xxxx
```

It should display the below result.

```
{
  "id": "lse3o7xxxx",
  "value": "VGUfTNfM7v9uysBDrU1Pxxxxxx",
  "name": "MyKey3",
  "description": "My Key 3",
  "enabled": true,
  "createdDate": 1528406609,
  "lastUpdatedDate": 1528406609,
  "stageKeys": []
}
```

Similar to `get-api-keys` call, `--include-value` is must here, otherwise actual API Key will not be included in the result

Now you need to convert the output in a format which can be saved on s3 and later can be imported to apigateway.

You can import keys with `import-api-keys`

```
aws apigateway import-api-keys --body <value> --format <value>
```

> --body (blob)
>
> The payload of the POST request to import API keys. For the payload
>   format
>
> --format (string)
>
> A query parameter to specify the input format to imported API keys.
>   Currently, only the CSV format is supported. --format csv

Simplest style is with two fields only e.g Key,name

```
Key,name
apikey1234abcdefghij0123456789,MyFirstApiKey
```

You can see the full detail of formats from [API Gateway API Key File Format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-key-file-format.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it in python using a lambda for backing up APIs keys. Used boto3 APIs similar to the above answer.

However, I am looking for a way to trigger the lambda with an event of "API key added/removed" :-)